# Reference a book without authors with a shortened title (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

I have a book without (known) authors. Its title is very long, so I'd like to shorten it in *citations*, but not in the bibliography. I've tried to use `SHORTTITLE`, but then that shortened title also appears as the title in the bibliography, plus the title in the citation appears in italics, whereas I would like it in an upright font.

I.e. I would like to see this in the citation:

> I like the *IPA* (Handbook of the IPA 1999)

And this in the bibliography:

> *Handbook of the International Phonetic Association. A guide to the use of the International Phonetic Alphabet* (1999). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

But this is as far as I have gotten with it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{ipa1999,
    TITLE = "Handbook of the International Phonetic Association",
    YEAR = "1999",
    LOCATION = "Cambridge",
    PUBLISHER = "Cambride University Press",
    SHORTTITLE = "Handbook of the IPA",
    SUBTITLE = "A guide to the use of the International Phonetic Alphabet"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
I like the \textit{IPA} \parencite{ipa1999}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the bibliography macro which prints the label. For authoryear the order is:

- label
- shorttitle
- title

So you can change the order to:

- label
- title
- shorttitle

Here the mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{ipa1999,
    TITLE = "Handbook of the International Phonetic Association",
    YEAR = "1999",
    LOCATION = "Cambridge",
    PUBLISHER = "Cambride University Press",
    SHORTTITLE = "Handbook of the IPA",
    SUBTITLE = "A guide to the use of the International Phonetic Alphabet"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{labeltitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{label}%
    {\iffieldundef{title}%
       {\printfield{shorttitle}%
        \clearfield{shorttitle}}%
       {\printfield{title}\clearfield{title}}}%
    {\printfield{label}}}
\begin{document}
I like the \textit{IPA} \parencite{ipa1999}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to decide whether it's best to put the year after ``TITLE`` (default) or after ``SUBTITLE``, but I think the default looks good here. Do you also have a solution for using an upright font in citations with ``SHORTTITLE``?

Comment: @Sverre: Use `\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1}`